# How to configure fault and upgrade domains in Azure service fabric template?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I've default service fabric ARM template and I'm trying to configure faultDomain and upgradeDomain in ARM template. I have this manual [msdocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description#upgrade-domains) but I didn't recognize where in ARM template I could specify node values.

```
{
  "apiVersion": "[variables('sfrpApiVersion')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters",
  "name": "[parameters('clusterName')]",
  "location": "[parameters('clusterLocation')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('supportLogStorageAccountName'))]"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doe

If you are hosting in Azure hosted Service Fabric deployments then you cannot configure fault and upgrade domains because according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description#configuring-fault-and-upgrade-domains):

> Defining Fault Domains and Upgrade Domains is done automatically in Azure hosted Service Fabric deployments. Service Fabric picks up and uses the environment information from Azure.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that Azure Service Fabric uses an Azure VMSS (Virtual Machine Scale Set) to provide compute (VMs), this automatically spreads a set of VMs across five fault domains. The idea being that it makes auto-scaling much easier. Although there is additional configuration needed to auto-scale Service Fabric.

Unless you manually deploy Service Fabric, you have no control over fault or update domains.